# Getting current time during a BrickEvent Haskell

Tags: haskell, io-monad, tui

I'm relatively new to Haskell, and I'm trying to build a terminal user interface with brick. I'd like to record a timestamp every time a user input is given. To do this I wrote the following functions:

```
handleInputEvent :: TestState -> BrickEvent n e -> EventM n (Next TestState)
handleInputEvent s i =
  case i of
    VtyEvent vtye ->
      case vtye of
        EvKey KBS [] -> handleBackSpaceInput s
        EvKey (KChar 'q') [MCtrl] -> halt s
        EvKey (KChar c) [] -> handleTextInput s c
        _ -> continue s
    _ -> continue s
```

```
handleTextInput :: TestState -> Char -> EventM n (Next TestState)
handleTextInput s c =
  case c of
    ' ' -> do
      let cursor = text s
      case nonEmptyCursorSelectNext cursor of
        Nothing -> continue s
        Just cursor' -> continue $ s {text = cursor'}
    _ -> do
      let tstamp = getCurrentTime
      let cursor = text s
      let cur_word = nonEmptyCursorCurrent cursor
      let new_word = TestWord {word = word cur_word, input = input cur_word ++ [c]}
      let new_text = reverse (nonEmptyCursorPrev cursor) ++ [new_word] ++ nonEmptyCursorNext cursor
      let test_event = TestEvent {timestamp = tstamp, correct = isInputCorrect cur_word c}
      case NE.nonEmpty new_text of
        Nothing -> continue s
        Just ne -> do
          case makeNonEmptyCursorWithSelection (cursorPosition cursor) ne of
            Nothing -> continue s
            Just ne' -> continue $ s {text = ne', tevents = test_event : tevents s}
```

```
data TestEvent = TestEvent
  { timestamp :: IO UTCTime,
    correct :: Bool
  }
```

When I now try to evaluate the difference between the first and last timestamp I get almost 0, no matter how long the program runs.

```
ui = do
  initialState <- buildInitialState 50
  endState <- defaultMain htyper initialState
  startTime <- timestamp (head (tevents endState))
  stopTime <- timestamp (last (tevents endState))
  let (timespan, _) = properFraction (diffUTCTime stopTime startTime)
  print timespan
```

I think this is because getCurrentTime returns `IO UTCTime` but the handler Functions themselves are not IO Functions, so the timestamps are only evaluated during the `ui` block. Is there any way to correctly implement this functionality in brick without rebuilding the entire code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let tstamp = getCurrentTime` says “define an action `tstamp :: IO UTCTime` which is *the same as* the action `getCurrentTime :: IO UTCTime`”. You store this value in the `timestamp :: IO UTCTime` field of every `TestEvent`, so this:

```
startTime <- timestamp (head (tevents endState))
stopTime <- timestamp (last (tevents endState))
```

Ends up exactly equivalent to this:

```
startTime <- getCurrentTime
stopTime <- getCurrentTime
```

And I expect it’s obvious why you see a near-0 duration between them!

Instead, you should make the type of the `timestamp` field just `UTCTime`, and execute `getCurrentTime` in your event handler using `liftIO` to run an `IO` action inside Brick’s `EventM`:

```
tstamp <- liftIO getCurrentTime
```

Then you can extract the start and end times without I/O:

```
let startTime = timestamp (head (tevents endState))
let stopTime = timestamp (last (tevents endState))
```

This is a common struggle for people new to Haskell: `IO X` isn’t a value of type `X` that came from doing I/O, it’s a program that may use I/O to make a value of type `X`.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me. Upvoted. The missing piece for me was the `liftIO` function.

Answer (score 1):

After I read up more on the IO Monad I figured it out. I needed to write a function that gets the time and returns `IO TestState` and then use

```
liftIO (addTestEvent) >>= continue
```

instead of

```
Just ne' -> continue $ s {text = ne', tevents = test_event : tevents s}
```